# TYPO3 V11 t3d import preserve crdate and tstamp values

Tags: typo3

I am importing typo3 custom extension records from t3d that was exported from another instance. Say for example its an event records. After importing it, the event records crdate and tstamp values are changed to current date and time. But its very important for me to preserve those timestamp to see when it was created. And i checked that, same thing also happening to pages and tt_content records. Is there any setting or workaround to fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T3D import uses the TYPO3 DataHandler to create the records. This has the benefit of using the central logic that also normal data editing and insertion uses.

The DataHandler actually always sets tstamp and crdate to the current time:

DataHandler::processRemapStack():

```
if ($GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['tstamp'] ?? false) {
    $fieldArray[$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['tstamp']] = $GLOBALS['EXEC_TIME'];
}
```

and for DataHandler::process_datamap():

```
if ($status === 'new') {
    if ($GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['crdate'] ?? false) {
        $fieldArray[$GLOBALS['TCA'][$table]['ctrl']['crdate']] = $GLOBALS['EXEC_TIME'];
    }
}
```

so that means as long as the TCA for a table is defined, the current date will be filled in.

You could circumvent that if at importing you unset the TCA options of your extension for those specific fields (temporarily, only during import), but that's rather dirty and will have side-effects if your instance is being worked at during import.

I'll try to investigate why this is actually performed and let you know, if I find out :-).
*EDIT*: See https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/82494 for a patch and https://forge.typo3.org/issues/102844 for the issue I created about this - many thanks for getting this started, I think it needs addressing.

Comment: Removing this from TCA is worked.
'ctrl' => [
     'tstamp'=> 'tstamp',
     'crdate'=> 'crdate',
]

Comment: Remember to put in back in after import, otherwise you'll have issues with records of these tables :)

Comment: Addendum: Added a patch for this: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/82494 - edited the original answer to reflect this, too.